# HTML - new page with html section on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page with several classes, one of which I would like to access upon clicking a button. Is this possible? This is my current code:

```
<div class = "sign-in">
        <button id="myButton">Click to log in</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction, true);
        function myFunction() {
            alert ("Hello World!");
        }
        </script>
    </div>
```

But instead of having a pop-up window saying "Hello World", I would like the button to navigate to a new page, which is already constructed in the same html file, as seen below:

```
<div class="tabs">

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Scanner</label>

       <div class="content">
           Click here for your scanner
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>
```

Just not sure how to link the two.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of your whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `window.location.href` to redirect your page

For instance

```
<div class = "sign-in">
        <button id="myButton">Click to log in</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction, true);
        function myFunction() {
            window.location.href="mypage.html";
        }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if this is what you meant, but I created a new html file with the tab information that I referenced here: window.location.href="tabs.html"

Comment: glad to help! (: @cgp25

Answer (score 0):

The content you want to display are on the same file, so that is not a new page, but same page (In Tabs), so give your tab some name, for example

```
<div class="tab" name="MyPage">
```

and then replace

```
alert ("Hello World!");
```

with

```
window.location.href="#MyPage";
```